# Invalid Hash key in facebook app in android

Tags: android, facebook, key, facebook-login

I got hash key from below code in android:

```
try {
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),
PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
md.update(signature.toByteArray());
Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
Log.e("Name not found", e1.toString());
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
Log.e("No such an algorithm", e.toString());
}
catch (Exception e){
Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
}
```

But it was invalid key... Please suggestion how to verify hash key for Facebook login....

Answer (score 9):

You are getting the hash-key with debug key... Which may work if you haven't sign the package and running app in debug mode. What you need to do is :

1) Go to the manifest file and add to the application android:debuggable="true".

2) Sign the application, capy and install to your device manually or for use "adb install path_to_apk" from command line.

3) Now run your app and monitor the logcat.

4) You will get printed a new key which will be the matching key with key facebook app is showing in the error msg, The key you have got is now having a = sign in the last.

5) Register this key on facebook developer site

**Alternate Trick**

You can do one other thing Simply register key which is showing in the error msg "The key hash ### does not match any stored key hashes" Just add the = in the end of the ###. It will be like ###=

you are done!! Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks...I tried by generating my own hash key for signed version, but this didn't work. So I tried alternate trick.. Worked:)

Answer (score 1):

Add this function into your class,and call this function in oncreate methode,then generate sign apk and run sign apk in your device and check log-cat, copy generated hash key to facebook developer console.

```
private void showHashKey()
{
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.kisan.kisan",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }

}
```

Check facebook authentication,it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you might not have updated the keyhash in the facebook developer account. Refer the: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Generate the Keyhash using:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

And update into your facebook devloper site, under Apps tab, General Settings

Answer (score 0):

Assign this to a button's on click and get the Key Hash from the logcat.

```
Button getKeyHash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_key_hash);
    getKeyHash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Key Hash
            try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
                Log.e("Name not found", e1.toString());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Log.e("No such an algorithm", e.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Now go to your app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps
. Then click on settings, add your Key Hash and save.[image]