# facebook login not working on device correctly

Tags: android, facebook

Below is the link using which I changed the key hash for release apk in facebook

[App is misconfigured for Facebook login: Android Facebook integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue)

But it does not help, facebook login run on device if I install the app using debugger, but if I used the signed apk it does not; I know both will have different signatures and I have created keyhash using the same but got zero result.

Below is command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin> keytool -exportcert -alias ****** -keystore "E:\Neha\Uploaded_projects\***\abc.keystore.jks" | "E:\Neha\openssl\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "E:\Neha\openssl\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" -base64
```

Comment: checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929153/invalid-hash-key-in-facebook-app-in-android/25035885#25035885)

Comment: not working for me....

Comment: Use openssl-0.9.8e X64; worked for me :)