# Invalid key hash error, even though the key matches

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I get the following error when I try to login with facebook in debug mode.

[image]

Eventhough it matches the one I specified in the Developer Settings.

[image]

The following code prints out te same key hash:

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "hu.returpack.mindendoboz",
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result: `D/KeyHash:﹕ attaFrbPASaeKhWnrt8/oNcqd8s=`

I followed the guides closely on the facebook developers page, so I don't think there is any code missing.

Log in works perfectly when I generate a signed apk and installed that one on the device. It doesn't work in debug mode and I have no idea why. it's really annoying that I have to generate a signed apk just to test anything facebook related.

I tried using a brand new debug keystore, but it's doing the same thing.

Any helo would be appreaciated.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to enable developer mode on Facebook first?

Comment: What do you mean? I closely followed the guide on the facebook developers page adn there was no "Enable developer mode" step. And I didn't find any option for enabling developer mode.

Comment: The hash in your error screen is missing the '=' symbol at the end

Comment: @TmKVU You are very correct, because of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25035885/2968428), I assumed that the error shows the key without the '=' symbol by default.

Answer (score 0):

For now I solved it by using the debug key hash where the release key hash shhould be.